# UNIX2DOS Functionality

Tags: unix

> /bin/ksh -c "cat $PMSourceFileDir/RT/TgtFiles/$OutputFileStrPerfHdr $PMSourceFileDir/RT/TgtFiles/$OutputFileStrPerfCSV | unix2dos -437 > $PMRootDir/RT/Temp/$OutputFileStrPerfCSV"

I work in IBM enterprise server and unix2dos command is not found. Can you provide the alternative for unix2dos functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use awk or perl to do something similar:

```
awk 'sub("$", "\r")'
```

or

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/'
```

oh and also this if you need it:

```
recode latin1..ibmpc
```

Comment: awk dont give the exact results. Can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, as a pure shell approach:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\r\n' "$line"; done <in >out
```